# Reading from .txt file and importing data into 2D arraylist

Tags: java

I am working on Project Euler problem 11:
In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in red.

(I didn't include the numbers just so my question is easier to follow. If you want to refer to it, the link is https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.

What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

My problem is that I want to input this data into a 2D arraylist, but am unsure how. This is my code thus far. I know it may not that great of a way to go about solving this, but I am still learning, as you can clearly tell, and so don't really care about refining the code and making it simpler or shorter at this point. All I need is to know how to store it as a 2D arraylist, then I believe I should be good to go.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class main{
public static int row(ArrayList data){
    int product=1;//product of any four numbers in sequence across
    int max=0;//max product going across
    int item;//sets value of data
    int y=0;//counts position of data (1-4)
    int rownum;//number row
    int column;//number column
    Object num;//used to extract data from arraylist before converting into int
    for(column=0;column<16;column++){
        while(y<4){
            item=x+y;
            num=data.get(item);
            product*=(Integer) num;
            if (product>max){
                max=product;
            }
            y++;
        }
        product=1;
        y=0;
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    File path=new File("../numbers.txt");
    int word;//represents number column 
    int max;//max product of any four numbers in order
    int product=1;//max product of each individual way (across, down, diagonal)
    int line;//each individual number
    ArrayList data=new ArrayList();
    try{
        Scanner in=new Scanner(path);
        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            for(word=0;word<16;word++){//goes across a row
                line=in.nextInt();
                data.add(line);//adds file to arraylist
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
    max=row(data);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically a two-dimensional ArrayList is an ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, in this case you may want to use a 2D array like this (which is also an array of arrays):

```
int[][] numbers = new int[20][20];
```

Then you can input your numbers using a nested for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++){
        numbers[i][j] = /*yadda yadda*/;
    }
}
```